# align timeseries in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 time series.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([
        ['1/10/12',10],
        ['1/11/12',11],
        ['1/12/12',13],
        ['1/14/12',12],
        ],
        columns=['Time','n'])
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df1=pd.DataFrame([
        ['1/13/12',88],
        ],columns=['Time','n']
        )
df1.index=pd.to_datetime(df1['Time'])
```

I am trying to align the time series so the index is in order. I am guessing [reindex_like](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html)  is what I need but not sure how to use it.

Here is my desired output

```
    Time   n
0  1/10/12  10
1  1/11/12  11
2  1/12/12  13
3  1/13/12  88
4  1/14/12  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
df.append(df1).sort().reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you need to compile more pieces together, it is more efficient to use `pd.concat(<names of all your dataframes as a list>)`.

P.S. You code is a bit redundant: you don't need to cast `Time` into index if you don't need it there. You can sort values based on any column, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([
        ['1/10/12',10],
        ['1/11/12',11],
        ['1/12/12',13],
        ['1/14/12',12],
        ],
        columns=['Time','n'])

df1=pd.DataFrame([
        ['1/13/12',88],
        ],columns=['Time','n']
        )

df.append(df1).sort_values('Time')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df,df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print df

      Time   n
0  1/10/12  10
1  1/11/12  11
2  1/12/12  13
3  1/13/12  88
4  1/14/12  12
```

Or you can use [`ordered_merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html?highlight=ordered_merge#merging-ordered-data):

```
print pd.ordered_merge(df, df1)

      Time   n
0  1/10/12  10
1  1/11/12  11
2  1/12/12  13
3  1/13/12  88
4  1/14/12  12
```